# Search URL for a Year

Tags: php

I have a web address:

http://localhost/mysite/2014/?cat=4

Is there a way to test if my URL contains a year integer like `2014`?

I had tried:
`if(preg_match("/\/(\d+)$/",$url,$matches))` but no success.

Thank you

Comment: is the year always enclosed in `/` ?

Comment: It isn't. Is that my issue here?

Comment: Or am I doing this the wrong way? This is the only part of the site that uses `cat` - should I be searching for that instead? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://localhost/mysite/2014/?cat=4";

if (preg_match("/(\d{4})/", $url, $matches))
{
    echo "Match!";
}
else
{
    echo "No match";
}
```

This regex matches 4 consecutive digits, anywhere in the string.

Comment: you need to add `/` to the start and end of the preg_match quotes.

Comment: And you need to remove your first slash because it is making the regex find a literal "d" . this answer is incorrect as it stands.

Comment: This worked great for me! My `$url` was at fault originally - was targeting the script & not the address bar.

Comment: If a post worked for you please accept it as an answer so that people don't waste their time at trying to answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be:

```
$pUrl = parse_url($url);
$path = $pUrl['path'];
$pathElems = explode('/',$path);
foreach ( $pathElems as $part )
   if ( is_nmeric($part)  )
     ... continue with "year" value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try regex: `([0-9]{4})`. This matches the values 0-9 in a consecutive set of 4 min and 4 max.

```
$url = "http://localhost/mysite/2014/?cat=4";

if (preg_match("/([0-9]{4})/",$url, $matches))
{
    echo "Match!";
    $matches[0] = 2014;
}
```